# Как скомпилировать игру из Unity под IOS без Xcode?

Tags: unity3d

Здраствуйте, я хочу скомпилировать игру которую сделал на unity по IOS, но у меня нет макбука и я не могу установить Xcode. Как можно скомпилировать игру без Xcode ?
Может есть аналоги Xcode под Windows.

Answer (score 1):

`ios` закрытая система.

Если ты не `appledeveloper`, даже с `xcode` вообще ничего не сделать. Даже если ты `appledeveloper`, никакого откомпелированного файла, который можно запустить на устройстве на руки ты не получишь.

Только запустить проект на устройстве через `xcode` напрямую на зарегистрированных тобой устройствах разработчика или залить в сервис с которого можно скачать на тех же устройствах, что делается так-же с участием `xcode`.

Comment: Подтверждаю как человек с маком. Там нужно поиграться с бубном что бы скомпилировать даже на свой девайс.